# Word Problems about Probability

Tags: probability, word-problem

1. A coin is tossed twice. What's the probability that exactly 1 head occurs?
2. A coin is tossed 5 times in succession. What's the probability that at least 1 head occurs?

On #1, I'm guessing it's 1/2 because the sample space could be {HH,HT,TH,TT}. Four possibilities in total, two of which have exactly one head occurring.

On #2, I have no idea how to tackle this one, but my assumption is to multiple 1/2 five times.

Any help will do. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the first problem, I assume you meant to say that exactly *one* head occurs in two of the four possible outcomes.

Comment: You're right. I was having a hard time constructing a sentence that would fit what I know. Thank you for the correction.

Comment: I have edited to make it more accurate.

Answer (score 2):

You're absolutely right on the first question. Each outcome in the sample space is equally likely with probability $.25$. Since we have two outcomes wit one head $2 * .25 = \frac{1}{2}$

Now for the second problem. Whenever you see **at least** we should always think of the rule of complements. So

$$P(\text{at least 1 Head}) = 1 - P(\text{no heads})$$

Now what is $P(\text{no heads})$? Well this is the situation we have 5 Tails
$$P(\text{no heads}) = P(\text{5 Tails}) = (\frac{1}{2})^5 = \frac{1}{32}$$

Now returning to $P(\text{at least 1 Head})$

$$P(\text{at least 1 Head}) = 1 - P(\text{no heads}) \\ = 1 - \frac{1}{32} = \frac{31}{32}$$

Oh, and of course I am assuming this is a **fair** coin, otherwise we'd just replace the probability of heads with $p$